# The Diameter of resulting graph by sum of two unions.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Let's say we have a graph $T$, which is also a spanning tree of a graph $G$, $T$ is connected, now let's say the diameter of $T$ is $x$.

Now, what would be the diameter of :

$$
(T \cup T^c) + (T \cup T^c)
$$

where $T^c$ is the complement of $T$, and we assume that $T$, $T^c$ are the different copies of $T$.

What I know is since $T$ and $T^c$ are disjoint, the union of them will be a disconnected graph, but I'm not clear how the join operation denoted by $+$ sign here change the final resulting graph. Is it still disconnected? (which I hope not)

My idea was that the union of $T$ and $T^c$ would be a complete graph, but it seems like it's wrong if I plot a sample graph. Hence, I'm looking for help. Thank you for any support in advance.

Comment: This depends a little on the definitions. What do you mean by union specifically, and what do you mean by $+$?

Comment: The union of two graphs G 1 = (V_1 ,E_1 ) and G2 =
(V_2 ,E_2 ), where V_1 ∩ V_2 = ∅ , is the graph
G1  ∪ G2 = (V_1 ∪ V_2 ,E_1 ∪ E_2 ). And the + signifies the Join operation of two graphs, which follows the standard definition of join operation of two graphs.

Comment: And this is the definition of join: 
Let G1 = (V_1 ,E_1 ) and G2 = (V_2 ,E_2 ) be two graphs such
that V 1 ∩ V 2 = ∅ . The join G1 + G2 is the graph that has the vertices and
the edges of the original graphs, in addition to the edges that connect all
the vertices of G with all the vertices of H.

Answer (score 1):

The union of $T$ and its complement $T^{c}$ is a complete graph $K_n$, where $n$ is the number of nodes in $T$. The diameter of a complete graph is ofcourse 1, since all vertices are connected to each other by distance 1. Hence, since the join of graphs $G+H$ connects every node of $G$ to each one of $H$, we obtain that the problem's join graph $$(T\cup T^c) + (T\cup T^c) = K_n + K_n = K_{2n}$$ is also complete, so its diameter is 1.